# How to invest in Japan's stock market from the UK

Tags: etf, currency, foreign-currency

I live in the UK. I would like to invest in an Asian stock market, say Japan's, ideally in the main index, in order to have exposure to the currency rate change in addition to the index exposure.

How can I do that? I've looked into the main investment platforms (H&L, etc), but they seem to only offer euro or usd stocks, and with high fees.

Answer (score 3):

Use an exchange traded fund ETF, namely **SPDR MSCI Japan EUR Hdg Ucits** ETF.

It is hedged and can be bought in the UK by this broker **State Street Global Advisors** on the London Stock Exchange LSE.

Link [here](https://www.spdrseurope.com/resources/howToTrade.seam?tick=ZPDW%20GY&#).

Article on JAPAN ETF hedged in Sterling Pound [here](http://www.etfstrategy.co.uk/ubs-lists-eight-sterling-hedged-etfs-to-mitigate-currency-risk-on-the-london-stock-exchange-lse-63258/).

Comment: Why EUR hedged? Is there a GBP hedged version or unhedged?